# T SQL - splitting column into two columns after first '-'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Got dbo where i need to split it into two, after first '-' character. Working on SSMS 2014

example in spreadsheet:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh87s.jpg)

PartNumber holds data which needs to be break up. 
Part - Need to have all characters before first '-'
Number - need to have all characters after first '-'

Any help appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx). And to find the location where you want to split to `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, us [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT parts.PartID as ID,
Part = (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM STRING_SPLIT(parts.PartNumber, '-')),
Number = (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(parts.PartNumber, '-') LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1),
FROM dbo.PartsTable parts
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
SELECT 
    PartNum
,   REPLACE(LEFT(PartNum,  CHARINDEX('-', PartNum)),'-', '') as 'PartNum First'
,   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PartNum,CHARINDEX('-', PartNum), LEN(PartNum)), '-','') as 'PartNum Second'

FROM Part
```

The query above splits the PartNum string when it finds `'-'`, it then replaces it with a blank space so you have the result you expected.

I tried it and it works. Hope it's useful to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

Comment: It works, but not fully. It takes all before first '-' from left and put this into the column. Then second line takes rest and put into second column..but in 2nd part is '-' it will remove and join.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (PartNumber varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('HHY-12-1800-2'),
('FC-P-41-4')


Select PartNumber
      ,Part   = Left(PartNumber,CharIndex('-',PartNumber)-1)
      ,Number = Substring(PartNumber,CharIndex('-',PartNumber)+1,Len(PartNumber))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
PartNumber      Part    Number
HHY-12-1800-2   HHY     12-1800-2
FC-P-41-4       FC      P-41-4
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: @optimusprime Happy to help